# Rx Java Retrofit with flatMap runs only once

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to get a observable from a stream of button click then flatmap with another observable from retrofit to request an endpoint, but it only run once! When I click again, don't pass through the flat map method.

It's strange cause when the flatmap return others observables it runs okay, but with the retrofit one it only runs once.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    var retrofit:Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("<SERVER_IP>") 
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()

    var testService:TestService = retrofit.create(TestService::class.java)

    var buttonObservable:Observable<Void> = RxView.clicks(btnRequest)

    buttonObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap {
                Log.i("debug", "run flatmap")
                var request:Request = Request()
                request.accessToken = "<acess_token>"
                testService.test(request)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ user ->
                Log.i("debug", "user ")
            },
            { err ->
                Log.d("debug", "err: ${err.message}")
            })
}
```

Test Interface :

```
interface TestService {
@POST("protected")
   fun test(@Body request: Request) : Observable<User>
}
```

Request Class:

```
class Request {
    var accessToken:String = ""
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

EDIT:
In the end, what was happening was that the onError was trigger, which stops the stream.

The following code solve it:

```
buttonObservable
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap {


                try {
                    Log.i("debug", "run flatmap")


                    var blaService = retrofit.create(TestService::class.java)

                    var request: Request = Request()

                    blaService.test(request)

                } catch(t:Throwable) {
                    Observable.empty<Void>()
                }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ user ->
                Log.i("debug", "user ")
            },
            { err ->
                Log.d("debug", "err: ${err.message}")
            }, {
               Log.i("debug", "onComplete")
            })
```

But it's not the better way to do it, there's an correct way to continue the stream after hit the onError or onComplete?

Comment: is your observable complete ? (it shoudn't according to your code)

Comment: It runs the subscribe once.

Comment: try to debug this by adding a log in the click observable : `val buttonObservable = RxView.clicks(btnRequest).doonNext { it ->  Log.debug("click !") }` and add a onComplete call back in your subscribe : 

`.subscribe({it -> /* onNext */ }, {it -> /* onError */}, { () -> Log.d("onCompleted") })`

Comment: runs the click log, but not the onComplete.

Comment: I just notice something, it runs the error block, it will not run any click anymore, but when it runs successfull, still run the click

Comment: This is expected. Once your got an error, the observable is in a terminal state and won't emit anymore.

Comment: You can use `.onErrorResumeNext()` or `.onErrorReturn()` or other operators to decide what to do in case you need to fallback from error state...